# ¿Por qué Java no escoge el método sobrecargado con parámetro mediante autoboxing?

Tags: java, método, sobrecarga

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
public static void main(String ... args) {
    int valor = 30;
    metodoSobrecargado(valor);
}

private static void metodoSobrecargado(long valor) {
    System.out.println("Primitivo long.");
}

private static void metodoSobrecargado(Integer valor) {
    System.out.println("Clase Integer.");
}
```

Al ejecutarlo con Java 7, imprime en pantalla 'Primitivo long.', pero no logro explicar por qué sucede esto. ¿No debería imprimir 'Clase Integer.' debido al autoboxing que hace Java convirtiendo la variable de tipo entera `valor` a su wrapper `Integer` y seleccionando el método `metodoSobrecargado` que recibe como parámetro un objeto de este tipo?

Comment: Y cual es el código de funcionSobrecargada()?

Comment: Lo siento, corregí la referencia a metodoSobrecargado().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La razón es que Java va a preferir la conversión de tipos primitivos antes del boxing, es decir, ya que ninguna sobre carga recibe `int` va a preferir hacer el cast a `long` (Widening Primitive Conversion) antes de hacer el boxing a `Integer` (Boxing Conversion)

En cambio si el código fuera:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer valor = 30;
    metodoSobrecargado(valor);
}
```

O si el segundo método fuera declarado así:

```
private static void metodoSobrecargado(int valor) {
    System.out.println("Clase Integer.");
}
```

Entonces los tipos si considirian ya sea int o Integer y por lo tanto se llamaría a la sobrecarga esperada.

[Según la especificación de Java 7:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.3)

> ## 5.3. Method Invocation Conversion
>
> Method invocation conversion is applied to each argument value in a method or constructor invocation (§8.8.7.1, §15.9, §15.12): the type of the argument expression must be converted to the type of the corresponding parameter.
>
> Method invocation contexts allow the use of one of the following:
>
> - an identity conversion (§5.1.1)
> - a widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2)
> - a widening reference conversion (§5.1.5)
> - a boxing conversion (§5.1.7) optionally followed by widening reference conversion
> - an unboxing conversion (§5.1.8) optionally followed by a widening primitive conversion.

Traducción mía:

> ## 5.3. Conversión de Invocación de Método
>
> Conversión de Invocación de Método es aplicada a cada valor de argumento en una invocación de método o constructor (§8.8.7.1, §15.9, §15.12): El tipo de la expresión del argumento debe ser convertido a el tipo del parámetro correspondiente.
>
> Los contextos de invocación de método permite el uso de uno de los siguientes:
>
> - una conversión de identidad (§5.1.1)
> - una conversión primitiva ancha (§5.1.2)
> - una conversión de referencia ancha (§5.1.5)
> - una conversión de boxing (§5.1.7) opcionalmente seguida de una conversión de referencia ancha
> - una conversión de unboxing (§5.1.8) opcionalmente seguida de una conversión primitiva ancha

Es decir cuando el argumento `int` se tiene que convertir al tipo del parámetro sea `long` o `Integer` se escogerá primero según la lista el ***widening primitive conversion*** (de `int` a `long`) antes que el ***boxing conversion*** (de `int` a `Integer`)

Comment: ¿Siempre debo confiar en que esto ocurra? ¿La especificación del lenguaje trata sobre esto?

Comment: Si según la sección [5.3. Method Invocation Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.3)